# Repeat and while problems in loop with some condition

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, repeat

In my artificial problem, I need to remove empty values create during a sample process and make a new sampling process until I have just one value (`nrow(s.df)>0`). But, if the first condition is satisfied I keep the results (`res[[i]] <- s.df`) but if not, I need to make a new sample again and for this, I try to use `repeat` and `while` functions combining with `else` without success.

My example:

```
#Artificial data set
v0<-rnorm(20)
vNA<-rep(NA, 80)
v<-c(v0,vNA)
id<-1:100
df<-data.frame(id,v)
s_size<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

# Sampling using repeat
res<-list()
for(i in 1:length(s_size)){ # Loop for different sample size
s.df<-df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ] #sampling in data set
s.df<-s.df[complete.cases(s.df), ] #remove NAs
s.df
if (nrow(s.df)>0){
res[[i]] <- s.df# add it to the list
}
}
else{
repeat{
s.df<-df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ] #sampling in data set
s.df<-s.df[complete.cases(s.df), ] #remove NAs 
if (nrow(s.df)>0){
res[[i]] <- s.df# add it to the list
}
if (nrow(res.circle)>0){break}  
}
}
}
big_sample = do.call(rbind, res)


or

# Sampling using while
res<-list()
for(i in 1:length(s_size)){ # Loop 
s.df<-df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ] #sampling in data set
s.df<-s.df[complete.cases(s.df), ] #remove NAs
if (nrow(s.df)>0){
res[[i]] <- s.df# add it to the list
}
}
else{
while(nrow(res.circle)>0) {
s.df<-df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ] #sampling in data set
s.df<-s.df[complete.cases(s.df), ] #remove NAs 
if (nrow(s.df)>0){
res[[i]] <- s.df# add it to the list
}
}
}
big_sample = do.call(rbind, res)
```

This approach obviously doesn't work but if I don't use the `else{}`, I will overwrite the results that already satisfied the first condiction. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the NAs before the sampling if you are getting rid of all NAs anyway in your sample? Or if that isn't possible, you could also keep all results and do the filtering afterwards?

Comment: I cannot remove NA, because in my real problem several empty sampling happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `while` loop inside the `for` loop and make it depend on the outcome of the `if`-condition then you don't need the `else`:

```r
set.seed(42)

v0 <- rnorm(20)
vNA <- rep(NA, 80)
v <- c(v0, vNA)
id <- 1:100
df <- data.frame(id, v)
s_size <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

res <- list()

for (i in 1:length(s_size)) {
  condition <- FALSE
  while (condition == FALSE) {
  s.df <- df[sample(nrow(df), 3),]
  s.df <- s.df[complete.cases(s.df),]
  if (nrow(s.df) > 0) {
    res[[i]] <- s.df
    condition <- TRUE
    }
  }
}

big_sample <-  do.call(rbind, res)

big_sample
#>    id           v
#> 15 15 -0.13332134
#> 8   8 -0.09465904
#> 18 18 -2.65645542
#> 4   4  0.63286260
#> 6   6 -0.10612452
#> 2   2 -0.56469817
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>